# Esp8266 with Arduino and c# app communication over WLAN

Tags: c#, .net, arduino-esp8266

Hello everybody I have seen many tutorials on this topic but they all used the esp8266 as TCP server and c#/.net app as client and setup communication between the. But what I wish to do is get the esp8266 and the connected to the c# app to the same Wi-Fi network and then setup communication between them over WLAN.

I wish to use it for home automation and communicate between several different esp8266 and the c# app.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: What i can suggest you is instead of using WIFI or esp8266 use a HC-05 Bluetooth Modem and communicate through it. I was also using WIFI for home automation but used Bluetooth, Relays & Android App to do some automation. Although i can help you out as i am also in IMT Manesar

Comment: actually i am trying to make an app in c# to communicate to esp8266 with arduino using their ip addresses by opening a port on esp8266 the ip would be give by the wifi network. Thanks for your help.